# Found cyclical <include> chain: activity_maps_main includes activity_maps_main

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, maps

maps fragment and button is not showing and giving me this error

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/menu" />

<fragment xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map1"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".BM.MapsActivityMain"
    tools:layout="@layout/activity_maps_main" />
```

i want to show map fragment and button on it but having this error 
Found cyclical  chain: activity_maps_main includes activity_maps_main